# I have an ntp related mystery to solve

Tags: raspberry-pi, power-management, ntp

Today, whilst at work, I tried to SSH back home and couldn't get a response.
My initial suspicion was that it was one of two things:
1) Home internet down
2) Power outage causing things to reset

I got home to find that there had been a power out, which had caused my old Virgin router to reboot. I have this old router in "modem only" mode and it feeds internet only to a better Asus RT-AC56U router.

My Asus router had restarted properly and had reinstated the home network but there was no WAN because the old Virgin router hadn't reset itself properly.

I also have two Raspberry Pi's running Raspbian on my home net, and a headless server running Ubuntu. The Pi's had both restarted themselves but the server was still off.

I logged into the Pi's and ran the 'uptime' command to see if I could work out what time the power went off. Both Pi's reported they had been up for 7h40m, so I calculated the power to have been restored at 1040.

Both Pi's also had incorrect time. Both were behind by 23 minutes. I know that because the Pi doesn't have a hardware clock it has to rely on ntp to get the time on startup. When these Pi's were reset there would have been no Internet to get ntp from, so I'm guessing they took their time from some kind of last known configuration (maybe something in a log or systemd or something?).

So, power back on at 1040. Pi time out by 23 minutes.
1040 - 23m = Power off at 1017 and back on at 1040, right?

I booted my headless server to check some custom logs I have running on a cron job. One of these is to check the hard disk temperatures every hour, at 29 minutes past the hour, and append the temperature to a text file. The last temperature check had occurred at 1029 and been logged before the server went down.

But how/why were the times on both Raspberry Pi's 23 minutes behind?

I have rebooted the Pi's now and they've picked up the correct time from ntp.

I SSH'ed into the Pi's and checked uptimes and date before I restarted the Virgin box, so they hadn't had a chance to get any npt from external internet.

Comment: OK. I have shortened it and removed the landlord and workman bits. I live in a highly populated area of the UK and we just don't get 23 minute power outages. Ever. I thought that these details would lend themselves to explaining why I even thought it was possible to have lost power for that length of time.

Comment: If the RasPis don't have a hardware clock and rely on canary files or logs to storage to determine the time (notwithstanding NTP), then why would the time _not_ be off by the duration of the outage?

Comment: That is more or less what is confusing me. If the outage was between 1017-1040 as I caculated, then how did my server manage to log HD temps at 1029 while it was powered off?

Comment: Just grasping at straws here, but perhaps there were multiple outages, and over the course of one of them the power was not on long enough for pending writes to be flushed to the Pi storage media?

Comment: Hypothesis, which I haven't verified: something on your Pi (probably set up by Raspbian) saves the time every X minutes. If there is an outage then the clock is reset to the last time there was a time save, not the last time the Pi was up. So 23 minutes is the interval between the last time save prior to the power failure and the power restart, not between the power failure and the power restart. The time save could be a separate feature (e.g. a crontab entry) or could be something indirect such as a log entry.

Comment: I'm going with Gilles comment as the most plausible answer. All of my equipment is generally spot on WRT time whenever I check it, so the various ntp systems on my server and Pi's must all work. When I rebooted everything it autoconfigured the correct time. So I am convinced Gilles is right, and Raspbian must only log the time periodically (not every minute, maybe every 30 minutes or whatever). Then when my Raspbian machines rebooted due to power failure and couldn't get an Internet connection on restart then they must have defaulted to the last known logged time, which was 23 minutes out.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound obvious, but all elements use the same NTP pool as their reference, right? You’ve ensured all your configs are correct? Again, obvious, but had to ask. My servers at work are using the standard ntp.pool.gov or whatever but my systems are always SIX minutes different than our office internet, run by our IT but I am assured by IT their infrastructure is NTP sync’d same as my configs. Coincidence? Yeah, probably. FWIW, I’d say DopeGhoti is on the right track. What version are your Pi’s? I have an older RasbPi B+ v1.2 board in front of me and actually checked it for a backup battery to ensure thats not where the timing came from initially (which it doesn’t). How are you certain the time was correct on your linux server when the logs were appended? There should be a touch command (I think) you could use to get the delta.

Also - what were your stove, microwave, and every other digital clock in the house flashing when you got home :) ?

EDIT: It’s a longshot but check your Pi’s and your linux distro for fake-hwclock also.